# Tests fail, Unable to find native image

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am attempting to integrate a Quarkus webserver into a Gradle multi-build project. I have been following the typical guides for setting up a Quarkus service, but have come across an issue I can't figure out how to get around. At this point I am trying to get the default setup to run (with default code and tests)

When running the tests, I get an error saying that `Unable to find native image, make sure native.image.path is set`

I assume it is a configuration or dependency issue, but would not know how to resolve it, as I am new to Quarkus, and it's Gradle support seems to be fairly lacking...

I believe that I have setup GraalVM correctly (with the native-image executable).

[Project, in case you want to dig.](https://github.com/GregJohnStewart/task-timekeeper) Let me know what else, if anything would be good to include here.

**build.gradle of the sub project:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus' version '0.26.0'
}
//apply plugin: 'io.quarkus'

version = '0.0.0.63'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":BaseCode")

    implementation enforcedPlatform('io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:0.26.0')
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    //implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson'
    //implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-elytron-security'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.3.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileJava {
    println "WebServer version at compile time: " + version
    dependsOn ':BaseCode:test'
    dependsOn 'incrementBuildVersion';
}
```

**Fail Messages:**

```
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 29'. Working directory: /home/greg/GitRepos/task-timekeeper/WebServer Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.native=false @/tmp/gradle-worker-classpath17037522129690074442txt -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 29'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 29'
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/greg/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.6/6936e700f0fb1b50bac0698ada4347a769d40199/groovy-2.5.6.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Gradle Test Executor 29 STANDARD_OUT
    2019-10-21 23:27:02,366 DEBUG [Test worker] (org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.logProvider(LoggerProviders.java:158)                                                      ) - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider


org.acme.rest.json.LegumeResourceIT > testList() FAILED
    org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [org.acme.rest.json.LegumeResourceIT]: Unable to find native image, make sure native.image.path is set

        Caused by:
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find native image, make sure native.image.path is set

org.acme.rest.json.FruitResourceIT > testAdd() SKIPPED

org.acme.rest.json.FruitResourceIT > testList() SKIPPED

org.acme.rest.json.LegumeResourceTest > testList() SKIPPED

org.acme.rest.json.FruitResourceTest > testAdd() SKIPPED

org.acme.rest.json.FruitResourceTest > testList() SKIPPED

6 tests completed, 1 failed, 5 skipped
Finished generating test XML results (0.0 secs) into: /home/greg/GitRepos/task-timekeeper/WebServer/build/test-results/test
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.0 secs) into: /home/greg/GitRepos/task-timekeeper/WebServer/build/reports/tests/test
:WebServer:test (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 1.544 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: The `0.26` versions is going to fix and change some Gradle  handling. When it's released, a generated gradle project will be setup correctly and you shouldn't see this

Comment: @geoand I see the `0.26` just came out, happen to be able to point out some documentation on generating said project?

Comment: You can do this for example: `mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.26.1:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=myproject -DclassName="org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResource" -Dpath="/hello" -DbuildTool=gradle -Dextensions="resteasy"`

Comment: You can also use https://code.quarkus.io/

Comment: code.quarkus.io doesn't seem to provide gradle support. Going to try out that command.

Comment: It will soon, I guess it hasn't been deployed yet.

Comment: After waiting for 1.0.1 to come out, I have taken another stab at this. With the updates to the code, it gets farther but not quite there. I can run a test/ assemble of the code just fine, but the check task fails. Will make a new question to address this rather than reworking this question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the new question?

Comment: Haven't made it yet... Still fiddling/ making the best attempt I can before posting. Will post it if/when I do though. Also might turn into a bug report on GitHub

Comment: Sure thing, thanks!

Comment: In the end, I was able to get it working. Still getting issues related to native image generation on travis, but I changed the job to not attempt that for now. I believe the core issue is already being addressed and will just have to wait for it to make it through the line. Thanks for being there to help though, @geoand !